# Force out of scope boost::bind to fail

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to create an example of binding a boost::function to a member function that goes out of scope. It is still possible to call this function, even though the object no longer exists.

I need to prove that it is not a correct use and the app needs to fail. But the memory location still seems to be in tact, so I need a way to make it fail.

The other question asked would be: am I right? Is there something I might be missing?

```
class bad_object {
    public:
    void fct1() {cout << "Fct 1 called. String value: " << sth << endl;};
    void fct2(int i) {cout << "Fct 2 with param " << i << endl;};
    string sth;
};


int main()
{
    bad_object b;
    boost::function<void ()>    f1(boost::bind( &bad_object::fct1, b ));
    boost::function<void ()>    f2(boost::bind( &bad_object::fct2, b, 10 ));

    boost::function<void ()>    f3;
    {
        bad_object c;
        c.sth = "There once was a cottage";
        f3 = boost::bind( &bad_object::fct1, c );
    }
    // c now goes of scope, f3 should therefore be invalid

    f3();

    return 0;
}
```

output as expected.

```
Fct 1 called. String value:
Fct 2 with param 10
Fct 1 called. String value: There once was a cottage
```

Comment: If there is no data member in your class, I don't see why there should be an memory access problem.

Comment: That is very true. I edited in a member variable. The example is very simple, I know.

Comment: @TingL Welcome to undefined behaviour. It's just /outlawed/ to call instance methods on undefined objects (`this`). Think of vtables. They're data too

Comment: @sehe Certainly this is a ill-conditioned use case. I am not familiar with how vtables are implemented. Are they supposed to be for each class instead of for an instance/object of a class? If so, wouldn't the vtable still be there, regardless of whether an object is valid?

Comment: @TingL It's implementation defined. The only relevant source here is the standard. And yes, the vtable will be there, but the vtable pointer won't! (Now, for POD types you can probably argue that calling members that don't access members is probably fine)

Comment: the example does so (after Ting L pointed it out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you use `weak_ptr`: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3962a26e67cbf144)**

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/weak_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    int foo() const 
    {
        return 42;
    }
    virtual ~X() {
        std::cout << "I'm stepping out here\n";
    }
};

int weak_call(int (X::*ptmf)() const, boost::weak_ptr<X> const& wp) 
{
    auto locked = wp.lock();
    if (!locked)
        throw boost::bad_weak_ptr();

    return ((*locked).*ptmf)();
}

int main()
{
    boost::function<int()> bound_foo;

    {
        auto x = boost::make_shared<X>(); 
        bound_foo = boost::bind(weak_call, &X::foo, boost::weak_ptr<X>(x));

        std::cout << "Bound foo returns: " << bound_foo() << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "Bound foo returns: " << bound_foo() << "\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
Bound foo returns: 42
I'm stepping out here
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::bad_weak_ptr'
  what():  tr1::bad_weak_ptr
```

A more generalized version (that allows n-ary member function, optionally `const`-qualified) [is here (requiring c++11): **coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd535a7c757de061)

Comment: I am aware of the shared_ptr implementation. My point is to find a non-deniable example of the opposite ;)

Comment: It can't be done, because you need instance tracking. You can use `boost::enable_shared_from_raw` with a registration facility, but that's just hiding the shared_ptr. Or you can roll your own tracking facility, but then you're just reinventing the wheel.

Comment: In case you're interested: here's a slightly modified version that uses a `weak_ptr` so it will /fail/ the invocation instead of keeping the instance alive: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52463a3a02456061. (I think this is really tough to make generic in C++03. In c++14, I suppose it wouldn't quite be such a big task)

Comment: Here's a stab at a more generalized version in c++11 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7ad8e737ea42936

Comment: The weak_ptr implementation throwing a bad_weak_ptr is what I was looking for.

Comment: would you for sake of completeness replace the content of the accepted answer?